# StepAIC() stopping point

Tags: r, regression, variable-selection

I am trying to understand the stopping point of `StepAIC()`. When using `direction = 'backward'`, does it stop if any further deletion of the terms no longer decreases model AIC? Example as follows:

```
fm<- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
require(MASS)
fit_fm <- stepAIC(fm, direction = 'backward')
#The final step stopped at:
Step:  AIC=61.31
mpg ~ wt + qsec + am

       Df Sum of Sq RSS  AIC
<none>              169 61.3
- am    1      26.2 195 63.9
- qsec  1     109.0 278 75.2
- wt    1     183.3 353 82.8
```

Does this mean deleting any of the terms wt, qsec, or am will not decrease model AIC at all (i.e., all AICs=61.31)?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, backwards starts with all variables and takes everything out, keeps the best AIC then proceeds to repeat this process until taking one variable out stops improving AIC, it may not select the best model if, for example, it is "hidden" one layer deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  You can check this yourself (the *second* value from `extractAIC()` is the AIC):

```r
extractAIC(fm_nowt <- update(fit_fm, . ~ . -wt))
## [1]  3.00000 82.79016
extractAIC(fm_noqsec <- update(fit_fm, . ~ . -qsec))
## [1]  3.00000 75.21711
extractAIC(fm_noam <- update(fit_fm, . ~ . -am))
## [1]  3.00000 63.90843
```

Note that the values returned by `extractAIC()` are different from those returned by `AIC()` in base R, but the *differences between model AICs* (which is all we really care about) *are the same*:

```r
 AIC(fm_nowt)- AIC(fit_fm)
[1] 21.48286
> extractAIC(fm_nowt)- extractAIC(fit_fm)
[1] -1.00000 21.48286
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the `extractAIC()` function @Ben Bolker!

Answer (score 2):

```
       Df Sum of Sq RSS  AIC
<none>              169 61.3
- am    1      26.2 195 63.9
- qsec  1     109.0 278 75.2
- wt    1     183.3 353 82.8
```

This table is showing you the AIC if you delete any more terms, with the `<none>` row being the current model.

If you keep the model as-is, the additional terms deleted are `<none>`, and the AIC is 61.3. Each other row shows the AIC if you delete those terms, (remove `am`, get AIC of 63.9, etc.). So you are correct, deleting any of the remaining terms will raise the AIC - you are at a (local) minimum for AIC.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor Thomas. I should have paid more attention to the last column